# lang parameter does not work in Youtube API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, caption, lang

I have a task of getting video with subtitles(caption) in the definite language
According to the query parameters [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters) I use:

> caption = true - subtitles filter
>   lr = en - original video language
>   hl = en - the primary language of the movies
>   [lang](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#langsp) = de - the language I want to get the subtitles

Query example:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?safeSearch=strict&strict=true&v=2&caption=true&key=XXX&q=football&hl=en&lr=en&lang=de
```

Result:

```
<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
    <error>
        <domain>GData</domain>
        <code>unsupportedQueryParam</code>
        <internalReason>Invalid query parameters:lang</internalReason>
    </error>
</errors>
```

Could you explain me the reason of this result?

Comment: I'm create [issue 3338](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3338)
Reply see there.
But questions remain.

Answer (score 1):

I also get lost in the youtube API but here is my understanding.

In the link you provided, the parameter lang is described with:

> YouTube supports this parameter for requests to retrieve a caption track.

The "problem" (for most developed at least it is a problem), you cannot request a video captions if you're not the uploader.
See [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_captions?hl=en)

> Captions for a video can only be created, retrieved, modified and deleted by the owner of that video. To perform these operations for a video, you must submit authenticated API requests for which the video's owner is the logged-in user. Accordingly, API requests for caption operations must contain a properly formatted Authorization header.

That's why I think you shouldn't be able to do what you want to do.